# Run multiple Docker container on same port with different URLs

Tags: docker

In docker ss there a way to run multiple containers on same port but with different public URL?
Lets say instead of x.x.x.x:8090 use something like:
site

- site1.example.com:8090
- site2.example.com:8090

something like this:

```
docker run --name test1 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.example.com -p 8090:80 -e AUTHOR="test1" -d -P dockersamples/static-site
docker run --name test2 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=site2.example.com -p 8090:80 -e AUTHOR="test2" -d -P dockersamples/static-site
```

Comment: I dont think its possible. Which site should server the query if a request is received at `0.0.0.0:8090`. Both will try to send their response because at the end, everything is mapped to sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically use a proxy like nginx to accomplish this where the proxy runs in a container on the same network as your other containers. You can then use the Docker service name for the proxy backend source.

Comment: Can you give an example with docker-compose?